# StreamWriter in a Unity C# program

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have written the following code in order for my Unity app to write something to file:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

public class StreamManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start ()
    {
        WriteToFile();
    }

    void Update ()
    {}

    public static void WriteToFile()
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter( Application.persistentDataPath + "table.txt" );

        sw.WriteLine( "Generated table of 1 to 10" );
        sw.WriteLine( "" );

        for ( int i = 1; i <= 10; i++ )
        {
            for ( int j = 1; j <= 10; j++ )
            {
                sw.WriteLine( "{0}x{1}= {2}", i, j, (i*j) );
            }

            sw.WriteLine( "====================================" );
        }

        Console.WriteLine( "Table successfully written to file!" );

        sw.Close();
    }
}
```

However, the last line (*Table successfully written to file!*) is not written to the text file.

Why is that?  What am I missing here?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write it to console output, not to the file

```
Console.WriteLine( "Table successfully written to file!" );
```

This works:

```
sw.WriteLine( "Table successfully written to file!" );
```

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
sw.WriteLine( "Table successfully written to file!" );
```

instead of

```
Console.WriteLine( "Table successfully written to file!" );
```